# Raise an event in C#

Tags: c#, events, raise

I came across this question in a Microsoft Practice Test and I got confused. Here is the question:

> Which of the following C# code samples
>   is the proper way to raise an event,
>   assuming that the Alarm event, the
>   AlarmEventArgs class, and the
>   AlarmEventHandler delegate have been
>   declared?

Here is the "correct" answer they provided:

```
AlarmEventArgs e = new AlarmEventArgs(1, 2);
AlarmEventHandler handler = Alarm; 
if (handler != null) 
{ 
    handler(this, e);
}
```

However, there is also another answer which seems correct.

```
AlarmEventArgs e = new AlarmEventArgs(1, 2);
if (Alarm!= null) 
{ 
    Alarm (this, e);
}
```

I personally, always use the second method. It works just fine. Can someone please tell me why I should use the first method instead of second?

Answer (score 7):

In a multi-threaded environment, it's possible that the event handler may be updated while your event is being dispatched.  To avoid this scenario, you assign the handler to a local variable before checking for null and dispatching the message.