# How to Raise Event in WP8

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-8, raiseevent

**How to Raise Event in WP8**

As title, in WP8 there is no RaiseEvent() method. So, I can't do something like that. I need to activate an event in code.

Please help me!

Comment: [Have you tried this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1344972/2681948)?

Comment: Please add what you've tried. The page linked above is a fine example of how to call an event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Event-Delegate mechanism of .Net for this do like this:

//Declare Delegate and Event like this:

```
public delegate void YourDelegate();        
public event YourDelegate YourEvent;
```

// Fire YourEvent from your code like this:

```
if (YourEvent!= null)
{
    YourEvent();
}
```

Say you did this in `YourClass.cs` then in suppose MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
YourClass object=new YourClass();       
// Register HttpEvent event
object.YourEvent+= Handler_YourEvent;
```

add event handler in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
void Handler_YourEvent()
{
//code to handle event
}
```

Hope this Helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want to have a Tap Event,

use += to attach event handler in C#

```
MyButton.Tap += onTouch;
```

[`Events for Windows Phone 8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc189018%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: While there wasn't much to the original question, it wasn't about attaching events.